# dynamically highlight block with highlight.js in vue app

Tags: vue.js, highlight.js

I have a `VueJS` where I have created a component for rendering the contents from a `WYSIWYG` component ([tiptap](https://tiptap.dev)).

I have the following content being returned from the backend

```js
let x = 0;

enum A {}
function Baa() {}
```

I'm using [highlight.js](https://highlightjs.org/) to highlight this code snippet in the following manner:

```js
import { defineComponent, h, nextTick, onMounted, onUpdated, ref, watch } from 'vue';
// No need to use a third-party component to highlight code
// since the `@tiptap/extension-code-block-lowlight` library has highlight as a dependency
import highlight from 'highlight.js'

export const WYSIWYG = defineComponent({
  name: 'WYSIWYG',
  props: {
    content: { type: String, required: true },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const root = ref<HTMLElement>(null);

    const highlightClass = 'hljs';

    const hightlightCodes = async () => {
      console.log(root.value?.querySelectorAll('pre code')[0]);

      setTimeout(() => {
        root.value?.querySelectorAll('pre code').forEach((el: HTMLElement) => {
          highlight.highlightElement(el as HTMLElement);
        });
      }, 2000);
    }

    onMounted(hightlightCodes);
    watch(() => props.content, hightlightCodes);

    return function render() {
      return h('div', {
        class: 'WYSIWYG',
        ref: root,
        innerHTML: props.content
      });
    };
  },
});
```

Now, when I visit the page by typing the URL in the browser, it highlights the `typescript` code

[image]

Whenever I visit a different page and click on my browser's "Go back" button, it makes the code completely vanishes

[image]

#### What I have tried

I can see that the line `root.value?.querySelectorAll('pre code')` is returning the correct items and the correct code is present but the code vanishes after the 2 seconds passes - due to `setTimeout`.

How can I make highlight.js highlight the code parts whenever `props.content` changes?

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

Use [Highlight.js Vue integration](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js#using-with-vuejs) (you need to setup the plugin first, check the link):

```html
<script setup>
const props = defineProps({
  content: { type: String, required: true },
})
</script>

<template>
  <highlightjs :code="content" language="ts" />
</template>
```

#### Option 2

- Use `computed` to reactively compute highlighted HTML of `props.content`
- Use sync `highlight(code, options)` function to get the highlighted HTML
- Use HTML as-is via `innerHTML` prop or `v-html` directive

```html
<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import highlight from 'highlight.js'

const props = defineProps({
  content: { type: String, required: true },
})

const html = computed(() => {
  const { value } = highlight.highlight(props.content, { lang: 'ts' })
  return value
})
</script>

<template>
  <div v-html="html" />
</template>
```

Comment: The problem is that the content is coming from the backend and it can contain other things besides just code. An example `<h1> This is a title </h1> <pre><code class="language-ts"> enum Foo {} </code></pre>`. Any way around this?

Answer (score 0):

In template you have to call a method instead of delivering to v-html your text code:

```js
import hljs from 'highlight.js/lib/core'; 
import ts from 'highlight.js/lib/languages/typescript'
import { decode } from 'he';

hljs.registerLanguage('ts', ts);
const formattedText = (text) => {
   if (text && text != null) {
      return highlightCodeBlocks(text);
   } else return '';
};

const highlightCodeBlocks = (text) => {
   const codeBlockRegex = /<pre><code(?: class="language-(\w+)")?>([\s\S]*?)<\/code><\/pre>/g;
        
   return text.replace(codeBlockRegex, (match, lang, code) => {
      code = decode(code)
      if (lang && hljs.getLanguage(lang)) {
         return `<pre><code class="language-${lang}">${hljs.highlight(code, {language: lang, ignoreIllegals: true}).value}</code></pre>`;
      } else {
         // Automatically detect the language for code without a specified language
         const autoDetected = hljs.highlightAuto(code);
         return `<pre><code class="language-${autoDetected.language}">${autoDetected.value}</code></pre>`;
      }
   });
};`
```

template: `<span class="" v-html="formattedText(text)">`

use 'he' if you want to highlight html code = decode(code)